# How to make the PHP HTML from drop down list remember the last selection?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to make my drop down list to remember the last selection by the end user. I probably have syntax errors but could not find where I am making the mistake(s). Basically I am using PHP for connecting to an mySQL server to populate a drop down HTML based form menu. Then I let the user select and create a web report. Though I want the last selection to be remembered in the form by default. Can you pls help with my not performing syntax below?

```
    <?php
        $mysqli = NEW MySQLi($host, $user, $pass, $name);
        $resultSet = $mysqli->query ("SELECT DISTINCT account FROM table");
    ?>
    
   <form action="" method="post">
    <select name = "formAccounts">
        <?php
            while ($rows = $resultSet ->fetch_assoc())
            {
            
                echo '<option value="'.$rows['account'].'"';            
                if($rows['account'] == $_POST['formAccounts']) echo ' selected="selected"';      
                echo '>'.$rows['account'].'</option>'; }

            }
                // Close connection
                mysqli_close($mysqli);
                
        ?>
    </select>

        <?php
          if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            if(!empty($_POST['formAccounts'])) {
              $selectedAccount = $_POST['formAccounts'];
```

Then the code continues with web reports...

Comment: That's what `if($rows['account']= $_POST['formAccounts']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ` should do.

Comment: Why do you set `$account_id` but not use it?

Comment: it was a legacy line I forgot there... I have updated the code above but still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($rows['account'] == $_POST['formAccounts']) echo ' selected="selected"';
```

//You are missing one "=" and a space before the first selected i think.

Comment: I have made the above updates but i am still getting the same error...

Comment: LEt me know if you have further ideas on what I could have left out

Answer (score 0):

wrong lines:

```
            echo '<option value="'.$rows['account'].'"';            
            if($rows['account'] == $_POST['formAccounts']) echo ' selected="selected"';      
            echo '>'.$rows['account'].'</option>'; }
```

correct lines:

```
   echo '<option value="'.$rows['account'].'"';            
   if($rows['account'] == $_POST['formAccounts'])
     echo ' selected="selected"';      
   echo '>'.$rows['account'].'</option>';
```

you had not started  "{" after if statement but end this .
So, syntax error.
you need to remove this closer "}" .

and also should be

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
```

not should be

```
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi($host, $user, $pass, $name);
```